# How to add Blur.js to a bakground image when a Bootstrap modal window is opened and unblur when I close the modal

Tags: blur, modal-window

I have a Bootsrap modal window like this:

```
<div class="modal slacker-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="false">
 modal content 
</div>
```

When I open this modal I want to blur (with blur.js) the whole background, which is a slider. Every image on that slider have this class: `.vegas-background`

When I close the modal window unblur the background image.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this...in Bootstrap 3 you need to use 'shown.bs.modal'; in Bootstrap 2 it's 'shown'.

```
<script>

$( ".modal" ).on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {

$('.target').blurjs({
    source: 'body',
    radius: 7,
    overlay: 'rgba(255,255,255,0.4)'
});

});
</script>
```